# How to uninstall GlobalProtect VPN client?

Tags: vpn, macos

GlobalProtect VPN client refuses to uninstall the regular drag-app-to-trash way.

Their recommended method is to download the original `.pkg` installer and use its uninstall feature. This isn't always possible since GlobalProtect is branded to an organization and if you're no longer with that organization you can't download the installer.

Is there a way to uninstall GlobalProtect without using the installer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to run the uninstall script bundled inside the app:

```
sudo /Applications/GlobalProtect.app/Contents/Resources/uninstall_gp.sh
```